# How to use struct in impl?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to [implement a web server using using a thread pool](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch20-04-storing-threads.html) as described in Rust's documentation. The application's code is in *src/bin/main.rs* and the library's code is in *src/lib.rs*.

Trying to use `PoolCreationError` gives an error:

```
pub struct ThreadPool;

struct PoolCreationError;

impl ThreadPool {
    /// Create a new ThreadPool.
    ///
    /// The size is the number of threads in the pool
    ///
    /// # Panics
    ///
    /// The `new` function will panic if the size is zero.
    pub fn new(size: u32) -> Result<ThreadPool, PoolCreationError> {
        if size > 0 {
            Ok(ThreadPool)
        } else {
            Err(PoolCreationError)
        }
    }

    pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
    {
    }
}
```

```
error[E0446]: private type `PoolCreationError` in public interface
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 | /     pub fn new(size: u32) -> Result<ThreadPool, PoolCreationError> {
14 | |         if size > 0 {
15 | |             Ok(ThreadPool)
16 | |         } else {
17 | |             Err(PoolCreationError)
18 | |         }
19 | |     }
   | |_____^ can't leak private type
```

How one should cope with it and use the struct?

Comment: Here is a proper MCVE: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=779264cd1d675f36092aba170bd92d02&version=stable How are you currently interpreting the error message?

Comment: @E_net4, the error is the same.

Comment: You misunderstood me. What do you think that the compiler is telling you with "private type in public interface"?

Comment: FWIW, your documentation comment is incorrect — your function does not panic when the size is 0.

Answer (score 3):

`pub fn new(…) -> Result<…, PoolCreationError>` refers to `struct PoolCreationError`, which is private (by default items are private to their module).

Rust doesn't allow public functions to expose private types. You need to make the type public as well:

```
pub struct PoolCreationError;
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0446